# AWS SSH access key generation procedure and putting on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys

I wonder how does AWS EC2 puts the SSH public key on the instance and provides private key to end user. I mean to know how this process of creating an SSH key and putting it on EC2 instance is *automated*.

Comment: When you spawn the ec2 instances `AWS` asks you for keypair! This is how aws maps the public key inside ec2 instances

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keypair is passed to the instance via the EC2 Metadata Service.

From [Amazon EC2 key pairs and Linux instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#retrieving-the-public-key-instance):

> The public key that you specified when you launched an instance is also available to you through its instance metadata. To view the public key that you specified when launching the instance, use the following command from your instance:
>
> `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-keys/0/openssh-key`

An 'on first boot' script pre-installed on the AMI uses the above method to retrieve the public key and then inserts into the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Please note this method is slightly different if using Instance Metadata v2, as specified on the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

This process is actually carried out when the instance boots as part of the [user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).